# Unable to mount filesystem using python subprocess popen

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, popen

I am trying to mount nas filesystem using python subprocess.popen command, i am running a script to mount the filesystem. some how the script is unable to mount the filesystem.

My script:

```
self.mountSrc  = subprocess.Popen('mount'+' '+ self.src_m[l], shell=True)

print self.mountSrc

if self.mountSrc==0:

   print "Mounted filesystem:"+ self.src_m[l]
```

Output from my script:

```
Mounting: Source Mount Point:/rsyncTesting/source/share1
Starting:[................................................... ] Done!

mount: can't find /rsyncTesting/source/share1 in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab
1
```

I am updating the filesystem path in /etc/fstab before running the mount command. Also i am able to mount the filesystem manually as root user from command line.

slcnas888:/export/rsyncScriptProject_Source/rsyncShare1/.zfs/snapshot/SR_0000-0000000_Refresh_rsyncShares_RSYNC_PROJ_exp13April16 /rsyncTesting/source/share1

Comment: Could you please add the commandline you would use from the terminal?
Given that the code is only dealing with variables and some of the output shown has nothing to do with the code snippet, this would help get you a solution that you can then adapt

Comment: `mount: can't find /rsyncTesting/source/share1 in /etc/fstab` - it says it all really...

Comment: From the linux command line, i am running the command: "mount /rsyncTesting/source/share1" this is working fine manually. I am adding the filesystem entry in the /etc/fstab file and it works fine but with python subprocess it fails.

Answer (score 0):

I just modified the `mount` command to include the name of the mount point,
i.e. `mount /absolute-nas-fs-path /mount-point` instead of only `mount /absolute-nas-fs-path`.

I observed that in linux, when we add entries to the `/etc/fstab` file, running `mount <mount point path>` works fine from the shell, but in a python subprocess we need to pass both the filesystem absolute path as well as the mount point in the command parameter.

```
# self.src_fs[l] is an item from my list of filesystem paths.
# self.src_m[l] is an item from my list of mount points.
self.mountSrc = subprocess.Popen('mount ' + self.src_fs[l] + ' ' + self.src_m[l], shell = True)
print self.mountSrc
if self.mountSrc == 0:
    print "Mounted filesystem:" + self.src_m[l]
```